# How do you open .axd files?

Tags: data-recovery

I was sent some .axd files that supposedly have some data in them that i need to plot some things. However, I am struggling to find a way to open them. Any suggestions? They're binary files.

Comment: Try this thread:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879824/what-is-an-axd-file#:~:text=An%20AXD%20file%20is%20a,such%20as%20images%2C%20JavaScript%20(.&text=CSS%20files.,server%20in%20a%20standard%20way.

Comment: Why not ask the sender?